# What's the right project profile for my WVGA60 videos in Premiere Elements 10?

Tags: video, video-editor, premiere

I'm having [issues](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4230171) rendering a project with Premiere Elements 10. Basically it gets stuck at "Estimated Time: 00:00:05" and never does anything after that. After I click Cancel the program just crashes.

Someone had suggested I might have picked the wrong project profile for my videos. I tried various presets without much success. I even upscaled all my footage to 720p without much success.

Judging from this codec info from one the WVGA60 video I used, which profile do I need to use?

[image: GSpot info]

Comment: You haven't mentioned any details of the rendered output target such as resolution, file format, video codec, audio codec..etc. Just the fact that your rendering crashes at 5 seconds before completion suggests file format issues, but we'll need more details to know for sure.

Comment: I've tried multiple formats, including *YouTube Widescreen HD/SD* and *MP4 HD 720p 24*. Oddly enough I can successfully render a small part of the project, but when I render the full project it fails.

Comment: Correction: I think it's *MP4 HD 720p 60*, if that makes a significant difference. I specifically chose to film in a 60fps format so that I could slow down the material without having video playback become choppy.

Comment: ok: here's a workaround which tries to avoid the original error without trying to solve it. Render your entire project to uncompressed AVI with audio codec PCM/16/48k/2.0 and video resolution as the final intended resolution. Keep the frame rate as 24. Then load the rendered AVI in AVIdemux, and convert the audio-video to MPEG4-AVC/AAC MP4 or whatever.

Comment: Alright, I just tried rendering to AVI. I'm getting the same result... again with 5 seconds left. But any sign of activity faded away even before the countdown stalled. I also noticed that the output file never grew beyond 101MB even though I still have 10GB of free hard drive space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The advantage of rendering to uncompressed AVI is that you can render the project piecemeal and then join them together later on. So first, render only the entire project's audio to WAV. Then render the video (without audio) in contiguous chunks e.g. frames 0-200 to segment1.avi, then frames 201-400 to segment2.avi and so on. Once done, load the first AVI in avidemux and then do a file->append of segment2.avi and so on. Finally, from audio->main track, set source to external WAV and then browse & select the WAV. Now you can encode to final output from within AVIdemux.

Comment: Interestingly, when I render increasingly smaller parts of the project the program still crashes and stops writing data earlier. This is evidenced by the file size of the temporary video output file.

Comment: can you post screenshots of your project settings and of your render settings?

Comment: Just tried rendering a mere 30 second part... that fell through after 10 megabyte. I'm starting to think this issue isn't related to a certain problematic frame. Any thoughts? **Edit**: sorry, just saw your post. I'll get back to you in a bit.

Comment: Here are my current project and rendering settings: http://imgur.com/a/b0W2i

Comment: Provide the render settings for the AVI as well.

Comment: I use *DV PAL Widescreen* with 'Export Audio' disabled.

Comment: Are you producing your video for upload to Youtube?

Comment: No, but I might burn it to DVD.

Comment: OK. Assuming your raw footage is 848x480 @ 60fps; change project settings to match clip properties. Then render video only to uncompressed Microsoft AVI (_not_ DV AVI) with pixel aspect as square pixels (1.0) and keep resolution as 848x480. Keep frame rate as 60. BTW, make sure your footage is interpreted as 60fps. Check this by right-clicking the clip in media bin and going to 'interpret footage'. Hopefully this gets rendered without crashing.

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://imgur.com/a/CXHsz This profile is still giving me problems.

Comment: No, first, you need to change __project settings__ to match the clips. If you can't do that, open a new project with those settings and copy-paste the timeline. Next, you're still selecting a compression codec "Microsoft Video 1". Instead, it should be 'Uncompressed' or 'None'. I use Pro CS5.5, not Elements, so our options may not match. Also, keep field type to none or progressive.

Comment: Apparently I [can't](http://www.elementsvillage.com/forums/showthread.php?t=54620) make a video project with a custom width/height in Elements. 848x480 is not available as built-in preset, either. I used a new rendering preset for 'None' and 'Progressive' but I'm still having the same issue with the difference that it's now stuck on 6 seconds.

Comment: One final suggestion for now: use 1280x720 as settings but with 60 fps as timebase. If that doesn't work, upload one of the smaller clips and I'll have a look tomorrow.

Comment: Alas, [the settings you suggested](http://i.imgur.com/kNwsg.jpg) aren't working. Here's [an example clip](http://www.box.com/s/38178d81531106ae18b1) that was recorded with my camera in WVGA60 mode. It's a little dark because it's currently evening where I live.

Comment: So I imported your clip into CS5.5 with project settings as DV 24p widescreen. Added a color curves effect and rendered to [NTSC DVD](http://www.mediafire.com/?wu2bwawnj5nii22) @ 24 fps format. Worked fine. So without knowing more about Elements or your sys config, I can't help you out. FWIW, your cam is essentially recording NTSC DV Widescreen but in square pixels, and with a customized variant of H.264 codec called Ambarella AVC. So as a last ditch effort, you can try project settings of DV 24 or DV NTSC (both widescreen) to see if that works.

Comment: Well oddly enough I have no problem rendering a single WVGA60 clip either. It's driving me up the wall. Thanks for all your help -- I'll try your last suggestion. If that doesn't work I'll tinker some more with the upscaled 720p copies of my footage. Yes, I'd lose quality but at this point I just want to get the project rendered and never film in WVGA60 again.

Comment: You're better off conforming your clips to NTSC DV Wide i.e. 720x480. 720p is a lot of interpolation. Also, I just realized something. So far, I hadn't clicked on the link to your thread at Adobe. Till now I thought the render was getting stuck towards the end since you mention the estimated time left as 5 sec, but it's actually getting stuck at 10% completed. This strongly hints at a hardware bottleneck or configuration issue rather than a codec or file format or preset issue.

Comment: It's not consistently 10%, but it is nearly consistently 00:00:05. But long before that happens the program stops writing data to disk and Estimated Time Remaining timer just counts down to 5 seconds, then stops. Any thoughts on how I can find the hardware or configuration problem? I already installed the latest graphic drivers.

Comment: What's your virtual memory/paging file setting? And during your render, what other apps are running?

Comment: I can only use 3 out of 4GB (they installed 32-bit Windows on my 64-bit laptop!) but physical memory use was at 75% and processor usage at 99%. Background apps include antivirus, Dropbox, IM client, WinPatrol and Secunia PSI. Sometimes (like today) I have Chrome open. Aero is disabled while Premiere is running. Despite all the background apps I have no reason to assume they're interfering because physical memory is never full. Interestingly, the render tests I did to obtain these figures were successful. Same project, same render profiles, no problems. I'm trying a full render now.

Comment: My page file configuration is set to automatic.

Comment: Rendering went smoothly at ~69% physical memory usage. What the... How can this happen? I didn't really change my approach.

Comment: Once I was doing complicated work in Fusion on a comp with 2GB ram. Fusion would always crash during export after a few minutes. I checked the settings in Fusion and noticed that it was set to use 70% RAM. I lowered it to 65% and then all was fine. Since Fusion thought it could use 70% of RAM, it would request that much, but Windows & other apps had reserved in excess of 30%, so it wasn't actually there for the taking. I suggest trying my original uncompressed AVI method but first see what's the largest chunk you can successfully render, and then render the whole thing in chunks of that size.

Comment: I see your full render went fine. Congrats.

Comment: I'll be more careful about memory usage from now on. Thanks for helping me diagnose (what's likely to be) the problem!